# Javascript cookie issue with safari

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

I'm writing a web page which uses javascript cookies heavily, and it works for chrome and firefox, but not safari.

The cookie is just a simple string f.ex: `"11111asdjaksdljf9038jsomething"`. 
Safari adds an equals sign to end: `"11111asdjaksdljf9038jsomething="`. I've tried cutting off the equals sign, but it just ends up doubling the cookie like so: `"11111asdjaksdljf9038jsomething=; 11111asdjaksdljf9038jsomething="`.

Is there any way of forcing safari to accept the cookie as it is?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you use to set the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are expected to be used as key=value.  Could you not use an arbitrary key name and assign the string to it?

*your_key*=11111asdjaksdljf9038jsomething